# Replace in string, remove stop words

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon, pdi

I need to clean field from stop words from text file. How can I use filepath in Search in Replace in string?

Comment: You can't. But you can copy/paste in the `Replace in String` table of replacements.

Comment: It is not comfortable, if count of word is big :( so i wanted to get words from common file for my transformations any way

Comment: The other ways are even least comfortable.

Comment: You can also run a shell command and use sed. I know some people would say that's not the PDI way (input, replace, output) but it usually is faster and for big files it might make sense

Comment: thanks for answer, i used to Java Step in transformation.